# Embedding a Python code in HTML

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to develop a website which has currency converter as one of its parts. I have little familiarity with Python and HTML. I got a very short python code for currency converter.I want to embed it in my HTML code and I installed django but don't know in what file format (txt or pih) and where to save the file in order for it to give me the desired result. Thanks !

Comment: Django does not work by embedding Python in HTML like PHP or pih. It's a MVT framework. You probably should read the Django docs and tutorial. I think you could do what you want with karrigell or mod_python? Or a lighter weight frame work like flask might be easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use any of the template engine there you could be able to write your full python code as well by importing python libraries , 
Here is few web templates I prefer mako:

```
Jinja2 (based on Django's templating)
mako
Cog
Cheetah
```

Answer (score 1):

Python code can't embedding in HTML directly. You have to implement a web service.

If you want to design a simple it, you can implement [WSGI](http://webpython.codepoint.net/wsgi_tutorial) for your web service.

```
# This is a simple
def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    return ["Hello World"]
```

You also can use web framework such like [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) to let design easily.